# How can I leave a comment on a pending suggested edit (before it's approved or rejected), so that the editor can see it?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits, comments

I very recently obtained the "review suggested edits" privilege, and have already noticed two cases where the edits were useful, but deviate from the poster's original intent.  These edits added code to update pre-existing answers for modern language features; one could conceivably stand on its own as a distinct answer, while the other was a bit trickier: It's too large to fit in a comment, and IMO a useful addition, but one that I feel should be left to the answer's poster to decide.

Considering the first case, I would like to know whether there's an official way to comment on a suggested edit such that the edit's suggester can see it, or otherwise notify the suggester, before the edit is approved or rejected.  I know I can comment on one of their other posts, if they have any, but that feels like a hack.  I would prefer to not have to cast a Reject vote and put the comment there; I prefer leaving cases like this for the answer's poster to decide (since they're the one that'll be getting any credit/repercussions for the update, I believe they should be the one to get the final say, if they're still around), and don't believe edit suggestors can see reject reasons without actively checking their suggestion history.

At the moment, Documentation allows this: Proposed changes can be commented on, and the change's proposer will see the comment in their inbox.  So, considering that, does the Q&A portion of the site provide a mechanism for commenting on pending suggested edits for the suggester to see, or is "comment on one of their other posts" the best way to do it?

Comment: I think a `@name`-tagged comment on the post they've suggested an edit to will notify them.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It will?  I thought that only worked after the edit was approved.  That's useful to know.  Thanks.

Comment: No, it won't. [The user actually has to be in the edit history](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/153008); pending and rejected edit suggestions don't count for @ reply targets. Just put your rationale in the "reject" box.

Comment: Clarifying my post: I specifically mean contacting the edit suggestor _before_ the edit is approved/rejected, as is possible with pending edits to Documentation.

Comment: @CodyGray Would the edit's suggestor be able to see my rationale if I put it in the "reject" box?  Because that's the issue: I want a way to notify them when I believe that, for example, their edit could stand on its own as an answer.

Comment: Yes, they can see it. No, it won't notify them in advance, before the edit gets acted upon, but that doesn't actually do a lot of good because suggested edits get reviewed so quickly that they won't have time to "fix" the problem anyway.

Comment: @CodyGray Ah, okay, that should be useful, then.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks @CodyGray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you believe that edit is wrong - reject and provide reject comment if you want to and let others vote. Or "reject and edit" if you find edit unconditionally wrong (you won't be able to add comment in that case).

Otherwise skip is always good option. If you really want to comment to the editor - wait till edit is accepted and than comment with "@{editor name}" on the post itself.

Additionally if you find edit useful but too extensive - add you own comment to actual post with that information (credit editor too).

Comment: I think I need to clarify my post a bit, considering your answer and the first comment.  It's not about whether I think the edit is correct or incorrect, it's about whether there's a way to contact an edit's suggestor _before_ the edit is approved/rejected.  In the first case I mentioned, I wanted to notify them that their suggestion should probably be its own answer; this is because I felt that 1) it appeared to be correct, but 2) it modified the post enough that it should be attached to the editor's name, not the original answerer's name.

Comment: you can't. Edits are generally reviewed in a matter of minutes and there is no dedicated "before edit goes to real review" time. (Note that "it modified the post enough that it should be attached to the editor's name" means it is completely invalid edit - reject is perfectly fine for that).

Comment: Okay, wasn't sure if that was enough for a reject in and of itself.  The edits I referred to were useful, but significant, so I wanted to let the editors know.