# Rejecting attempts to reply: a way to notify them to leave a comment?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

While reviewing, from time to time I see suggested edits that look useful but should be rejected since they are attempts to reply (a technically correct change which was not present in the initial answer, a deviation from what they wanted to say). If the editor really cares, they will check if their edit were applied or rejected and add a comment accordingly. However, I wouldn't expect that from everyone especially experts in their field who spend not very much time at SO.

So, in terms of feature request, I'd suggest that the "attempt to reply" option is accompanied with a checkbox "suggest them to comment". A checkbox because it is definitely not each attempt to reply you would suggest to persist. One may add a comment themselves after rejecting (I've done that couple of times) but this sounds bad to me for 2 reasons: first, it is not instructive meaning that I'm doing their job instead of making them understand that they should bring their input in another way; second, I take their authorship which is kinda unfair.

Now, when such edit is rejected with at least one "attempt to reply" and "suggest them to comment" they recieve a notification that says something like "you edit was rejected but reviewers suggest to write a comment since your input looks valuabe". Not sure how to put it better: it's not short already, but it also should point the reason for rejection (should it?)

Comment: Hmya, it is not like they can't find out how to do this correctly.  There is this big blob of white space near the bottom of the page, inviting "type here!"  They could point big bobbing arrows towards it, flash the frame in garish colors, write a dozen help pages to tell how to use it.  But that still won't let them detract from the conviction that "somebody is wrong in the Internet, it is my job to fix it and it Is about bed-time". If you don't think that is a real problem then review what happened to the Documentation project.

Comment: Don't those making such edits often have less than 50 rep which would mean they can't add comments.

Comment: @HansPassant *review what happened to the Documentation project* would you mind providing some link to an article or clarify here? I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: @RobertLongson in my limited experience, not necessarily

Comment: If the editor doesn't care to check back, will a comment help? They'd still have to come back to the site to see it, right?

Comment: Semi-related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298501/offer-more-help-to-authors-of-bad-edits and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342506/how-can-i-leave-a-comment-on-a-pending-suggested-edit-before-its-approved-or-r

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298822/add-inbox-notification-for-rejected-edits, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267920/do-i-get-notification-of-accepted-rejected-edits